# Lightning Tab Gets Hang in Google Chrome

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

We have design a LightninG Tab that contains Lightning Component.
When we navigate to Lighhtning Tab then we can see our data properly without any issue.Problem comes when we try to navigate to standard tab or other Lightning tab,Google Chrome gets hang.We have to literally kill the google chrome process.

**Below is Lightning Component Code:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="ChartController">
    <aura:attribute name="chartData" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isChartDataEmpty" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="apexDataProvider" type="String" default="TargetReportDataProvider" required="true" />
    <aura:attribute name="chartTitle" type="String" default="SFDC Target Report" description="Title of the chart."/>
    <aura:attribute name="ISUOptions" type="String[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" description="Initialization process." />
    <aura:method name="refreshChart" action="{!c.createReport}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resource/chart_pure_min_css" />
    <div style="background-color: #fff; text-align:left; padding: 20px">
        <div class="slds-spinner_container" aura:id="spinner">
          <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner--medium slds-spinner--brand">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="color:#777; font-size:1.2em; margin-bottom:10px;">{!v.chartTitle}</div>
        <section class="slds-clearfix">
            <div class="slds-float--left">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <ui:inputSelect label="Select ISU:" class="dynamic" aura:id="selectISU" change="{!c.handleClick}" required="true">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.ISUOptions}" var="ISUOptions">
                            <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!ISUOptions}" label="{!ISUOptions}"/>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </ui:inputSelect>        
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <!-- Data Empty Message -->
            <aura:if isTrue="{! v.isChartDataEmpty }">
                <div style="width:100%; color:#aaa; margin-top: 10px;">
                    Data is empty.
                </div>
            </aura:if>
            <!-- Data Empty Message -->
        </div>

        <div class="slds-col slds-col--padded slds-p-top--large">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--col-bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                        <th colspan="3" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title=""></div>
                        </th>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.chartData.labels}" var="label">
                            <th colspan="6" scope="col">
                                <div  class="slds-truncate slds-align--absolute-center" title="{!label}">{!label}</div>
                            </th>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                        <th colspan="3" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title=""></div>
                        </th>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.chartData.subLabels}" var="label">
                            <th  scope="col">
                                <div  class="slds-truncate slds-align--absolute-center" title="{!label}">{!label}</div>
                            </th>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.chartData.datasets}" var="dataset">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!(dataset.subLabel2 !='Total') &amp;&amp; (dataset.subLabel1 !='Total')}">
                            <tr>
                                <td data-label="Name">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!dataset.label}">{!dataset.label}</div>
                                </td>

                                <td data-label="Name">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!dataset.subLabel1}">{!dataset.subLabel1}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td data-label="Name">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!dataset.subLabel2}">{!dataset.subLabel2}</div>
                                </td>
                                <aura:iteration items="{!dataset.data}" var="datadetails">
                                    <td data-label="Name">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-float--right" title="{!datadetails}">{!datadetails.data1}</div>
                                    </td>  
                                    <td data-label="Name">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-float--right" title="{!datadetails}">{!datadetails.data2}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Name">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-float--right" title="{!datadetails}">{!datadetails.data3}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Name">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-float--right" title="{!datadetails}">{!datadetails.data4}</div>
                                    </td>  
                                    <td data-label="Name">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-float--right " title="{!datadetails}">{!datadetails.data5}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Name">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-float--right" title="{!datadetails}">{!datadetails.data6}</div>
                                    </td>
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </tr>
                        </aura:if>  
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!dataset.subLabel2 =='Total' || dataset.subLabel1 =='Total'}">
                            <tr class="slds-hint-parent slds-is-selected" aria-selected="true">
                                <td data-label="Name">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!dataset.label}">{!dataset.label}</div>
                                </td>

                                <td data-label="Name">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!dataset.subLabel1}">{!dataset.subLabel1}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td data-label="Name">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!dataset.subLabel2}">{!dataset.subLabel2}</div>
                                </td>
                                <aura:iteration items="{!dataset.data}" var="datadetails">
                                    <td data-label="Name">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-float--right" title="{!datadetails}">{!datadetails.data1}</div>
                                    </td>  
                                    <td data-label="Name">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-float--right" title="{!datadetails}">{!datadetails.data2}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Name">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-float--right" title="{!datadetails}">{!datadetails.data3}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Name">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-float--right" title="{!datadetails}">{!datadetails.data4}</div>
                                    </td>  
                                    <td data-label="Name">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-float--right" title="{!datadetails}">{!datadetails.data5}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-label="Name">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-float--right" title="{!datadetails}">{!datadetails.data6}</div>
                                    </td>
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </tr>
                        </aura:if>
                    </aura:iteration> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>    
</aura:component>
```

**Below is the Lightning Controller Code:**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var cmpTarget = component.find('spinner');
        $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-hide');
        var action1 = component.get("c.getFieldPikclistValues");
        action1.setParams({"objectAPI_name":'Opportunity',
                          "picklistField":'ISU_Group__c'});

        action1.setCallback(this, function(a){
            var response = a.getReturnValue();

            if( !(response == null || response == "" || response == "[]" || response == "{}") ){
                component.set("v.ISUOptions", JSON.parse(response));
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action1);
        var action2 = component.get("c.getChartData");
        var parameters = '{"selectISU":"BS"}';
        console.info("parameter for ISU--->"+parameters);    
        action2.setParams({"dataProviderName":component.get("v.apexDataProvider"),
                          "parameters":parameters});
        action2.setCallback(this, function(a){
            console.info("Inside SFDCTargetReportController createReport : setCallback");

            var response = a.getReturnValue();
            console.info("Inside SFDCTargetReportController createReport : setCallback Response" + response);

            if (response == null || response == "" || response == "[]" || response == "{}"){
                component.set("v.isChartDataEmpty", true);
                $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-hide');
                return;
            } else {
                component.set("v.isChartDataEmpty", false);
            }
            component.set("v.chartData", JSON.parse(response));
            $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-hide');
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action2);

    },
    // Handle dorp-down change for ISU values
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper){
        var target = event.getSource();
        var attributeValue = target.get("v.value");
        console.log("current text: " + attributeValue + "Aura Id:" + target.getLocalId());

        component.refreshChart();

    },  

    // Load data from Apex Data Provider and draw report.
    createReport : function(component, event, helper){
        var cmpTarget = component.find('spinner');
        $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-hide');
        var param1 = component.find("selectISU").get("v.value");

        var parameters = '{"selectISU":"' + param1 + '"}';
        console.info("parameter for ISU--->"+parameters);    
        var action = component.get("c.getChartData");
        action.setParams({"dataProviderName":component.get("v.apexDataProvider"),
                          "parameters":parameters});

        action.setCallback(this, function(a){
            var response = a.getReturnValue();
            if (response == null || response == "" || response == "[]" || response == "{}"){
                component.set("v.isChartDataEmpty", true);
                $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-hide');
                return;
            } else {
                component.set("v.isChartDataEmpty", false);
            }
            component.set("v.chartData", JSON.parse(response));
            $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-hide');
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }


}

})
```

Can someone please tell me whats wrong or whats needs to be modified in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Doing multiple attempts I have found that css file that I am using in Lightning Component is actually causing an issue.

I have removed below code from Lightning Component

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resource/chart_pure_min_css" />
```

Even if I use the below Tag as mentioned by Christian, the issue is still replicate.

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.resourceName}" />
```

I am not sure why removing the css file reference from Lightning Component Code actually resolve the issue?

Anyone has a clue?

Does CSS not support in Lightning Component Code?

For now I am not facing an issue when Navigate from Once Lightning Tab to Another Lightning Tab.

Any Comment/Suggestion is always welcome :)

Comment: Well I have already answered the question but I want to know the css impact in lighting as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just a point in the dark: You should not use the `<link>` tag to include an external Stylesheet. Instead use a static resource and `<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.resourceName}" />` as the developer documentation states [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_css_external_platform.htm).

Comment: Even after removing <link> & adding <ltng> the page is still become unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling caching via Session Settings in Setup. This has resolved similar issues with unresponsive pages in Chrome since the Winter 18 update:

[image]

Comment: Cache setting is already enable in my org.Still the issue is replicable